# More durable rotary rotary lawnmower wheels?

Tags: wheels, parts, aftermarket-upgrade, lawnmower, replacements

What are some suitable replacements for modern rotary lawnmower wheels?

I have something similar to this:
[image: Typical push-style Masport lawnmower]
<sup>Typical push-style Masport lawnmower</sup>
[image: 7" (~175mm) Front-end Masport wheel]
<sup>7" (~175mm) front-end Masport wheel</sup>
[image: 8" (~200mm) Rear-end Masport wheel]
<sup>8" (~200mm) rear-end Masport wheel</sup>

I've had two crack & break already (both on the front-end), and I figure that solid (non-spoked) steel rims would be far less prone to this kind of damage. What do you guys think?

Is there any benefit to the plastic, spoked, faux mag-style wheels that most mowers seem to come with these days?